# Разметка XAML в Xamarin forms C# Tabbed + ListView

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Добрый день. Прощу помощи в создании разметки. У меня не выходит отобразить listview в Tabbed Page

для теста Grid отображается нормально, однако мне желательно сделать listview, а Grid'ом уже разбить разметку для своих элементов (они хранятся у меня во вью модели ObservableCollection BaseModel

в итоге Tab1 - отображается, Tab2 - пусто, помогите дельным советом как это отобразить

код разметки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App3.TabbedPage1">
<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="Name"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Test2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test3" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="Test4" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="ListView" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3">    
</ContentPage>   
</TabbedPage>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где у вас привязка то?

Comment: Text="ListView" обычный текст

Comment: Это так не работает

Comment: да сделал тестовую привязку - данные отобразились, я рассчитывал вначале сделать разметку и потом сделать привязку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кому интересно, для отображения listView вначале необходимо сделать привязку и потом только играть с разметкой

XAML

```
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="Name"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Test2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="Test3" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="Test4" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="phonesList" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Company}" FontSize="18" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Price}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3">

</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public TabbedPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Phones = new List<Phone>
        {
            new Phone {Title="Galaxy S8", Company="Samsung", Price=48000 },
            new Phone {Title="Huawei P10", Company="Huawei", Price=35000 },
            new Phone {Title="HTC U Ultra", Company="HTC", Price=42000 },
            new Phone {Title="iPhone 7", Company="Apple", Price=52000 }
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public class Phone
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```